# Validating user-provided control points for a Bézier curve

Tags: python, validation, coordinate-system

I have made some code which will validate user input for getting 4 control points for a bezier curve. It works fine however I was just wondering If I could make this code any more compact or efficient?

```
p = [] #empty points array

#gets 4 control points from user input
def get_points():
    #loops through 4 times to get 4 control points
    points = ["Start Point(P0)", "Control Point 1(P1)", "Control Point 2(P2)", "End Point(P3)"]
    for i in range(4):
        while True:
            #user input
            p_input = input("Enter X,Y Coordinates for "+ points[i]+":")
            #splits the string into x and y coordinates
            p_components = p_input.split(',')
            #checks to see if user hasnt entered two coordinates
            if len(p_components) != 2:
                print("Missing coordinate please try again.")
                p_input = input("Enter X,Y Coordinates for "+ points[i]+":")
                p_components = p_input.split(',')
            #checks to see if the values can not be converted into floats
            try:
                x = float(p_components[0])
                y = float(p_components[1])
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid coordinates", p_components, "please try again.")
            else:
                #makes sure user is not entering coordinates that will not appear on the screen.
                if(x > 1020 or x < 10) or (y > 760 or y < 10): 
                    print("Invalid coordinates, please try again.")
                else:
                    #appends the x and y coordinates as a 2 dimensional array
                    p.append([float(p_components[0]), float(p_components[1])])
                    break
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are things that can be improved:

- You could return the points instead of asigning the global variabel `p`
- You could split the function in two functions:

  1. `get_four_bezier_points`
  2. `get_point`
- it probably would be better to return float values instead of string values.
- You could inform the user that the input x and y values should be between certain values and must be separated with a comma.
- the error checking logic's could be restructured such that the second input statement can be removed.

Putting these together as an example:

```
def get_point(description):
    while True:

        p_input = input("Enter X,Y Coordinates for " + description + ": ")
        p_components = p_input.split(',')

        if len(p_components) != 2:
            print("Not two comma seperated values, please try again")
            continue # (jumps to the beginning of the while loop)

        try:
            x = float(p_components[0])
            y = float(p_components[1])
        except ValueError:
            print("No float values, please try again.")
            continue

        if(x > 1020 or x < 10) or (y > 760 or y < 10): 
            print("Values out of bounds.")
            continue

        # oke values are good
        return [x,y]  # jumps out of the function and while loop 

def get_four_bezier_points():
    p = []
    print("Enter four bezier points with x in [10,1020] and y in [10,760]")
    points = ["Start Point(P0)", "Control Point 1(P1)", "Control Point 2(P2)", "End Point(P3)"]
    for description in points:
        p.append(get_point(description))
    return p

p = get_four_bezier_points()
```

Comment: If I were to return the points, then everytime I wanted to use the points I would have to call get_points and it would ask for user input every time. How would I go about splitting the function up?

Comment: @Zestyy99, you could call the function and assign the result to `p` as in `p = get_points()`.

Comment: @Zestyy99, i edited my answer and added an example

Comment: thank you, that looks a lot better than the original :)

Comment: Or even better imo: `return [get_point(description) for description in points]`

Answer (score 4):

- for the first test `len(p_components) != 2` you can enter anything
  the second time.
- your error messages are vague, they don't help the user to input good
  values

you could do something like that:

```
p = [] #empty points array

#gets 4 control points from user input
def get_points():
    #loops through 4 times to get 4 control points
    points = ["Start Point(P0)", "Control Point 1(P1)", "Control Point 2(P2)", "End Point(P3)"]
    for i in range(4):
        is_good_entry = False
        while not is_good_entry:
            p_input = input("Enter X,Y Coordinates for "+ points[i]+":")
            p_components = p_input.split(',')

            if len(p_components) != 2:
                print("Wrong number of coordinates, please try again.")
                continue

            try:
                x = float(p_components[0])
                y = float(p_components[1])
            except ValueError:
                print("Only numbers are allowed")
                continue

            if(x > 1020 or x < 10) or (y > 760 or y < 10):
                print("Wrong range. x must be in range [10, 1020] and y [10, 760]")
                continue

            is_good_entry = True
            p.append([x, y])

get_points()
```